# Does the size of the table affect performance of an Index-Match?

Tags: excel

Right now I am using Index-Match as a replacement for vlookup in the following format:

=INDEX(LookupTable,MATCH($A$1,$F$2:$F$6001,0),3)

where LookupTable is F1:J6001

Since I am looking only at the 3rd column, is there a performance hit for using the larger lookup table, or should I make the lookup table only F1:H6001 (i.e make the lookup table only the width I need for the individual index-match?

I understand that if the LookupTable was sorted (which I can't easily do) I could increase performance by not requiting an exact match for the index.

Comment: A small one, primarily loading more columns of the worksheet than you need. Use C:C and F:F.

Comment: Careful, that one row difference *might* return unexpected results. (the LookTable is 1:6001, while the match is from 2:6001.

Comment: @Jeeped Thank you.

Comment: @BruceWayne Yeah, my mistake, that's a typo. Thanks for the warning though :D